# Django tutorial 5 , 1044 Access denied for user @'localhost' database error

Tags: python, django

I am working on tutorial 5 , i tried running a test:

```
$ python manage.py test polls
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'myprojectuser'@'localhost' to database 'test_myproject'")
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_myproject', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'myprojectuser'@'localhost' to database 'test_myproject'")
```

I have tried mentioning the test_name in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_database_myprojecttest',
    }
}
```

I also ran ,"`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_myproject TO 'myprojectuser'@'localhost';`" and

```
CREATE USER 'myprojectuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myproject TO 'myprojectuser'@'localhost';
```

The two query commands above were run while setting up the database.

Still the same error. What should i do ?

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: Are you using it locally or Heroku,...?have made project with command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for the test database is formed by adding 'test_' to the name of the database specified in NAME.

If you are using Django < 1.7 then:

```
'TEST_NAME': 'test_myproject',
```

If you are using Django >= 1.7: then you should use TEST as a dictionary in settings:

```
'TEST' : {    
    'NAME': 'test_myproject', 
}
```

Currently you have:

```
'TEST_NAME': 'test_database_myprojecttest',
```

However you should specify the test database name in settings only if it differs from default one with "test_yourDbName".

If this won't help then you can switch to Sqlite ENGINE. With Sqlite the test database should be created in memory without accessing to a real db.

Answer (score 1):

While setting a database you have run:

```
CREATE USER 'myprojectuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myproject TO 'myprojectuser'@'localhost';
```

Which means your user don't have access to other databases.
Yet the test is trying to create it's own database 'test_myproject' (as per your error text). So you have to grant privileges on that database as well AFTER you created user myprojectuser. Just run these commands in your database console:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_myproject TO 'myprojectuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .* to your SQL query to include tables:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_myproject.* TO 'myprojectuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```